# How to unload ALL models in Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember-Data Store has unloadAll method for unloading records for given type. How to unload records for all types?

Answer (score 1):

Great question @jaaksarv. According to the Ember Core team, one would use the `App.reset()` method to:

1. Clear all the data in the Ember container.
2. Rebuild the container anew and then route back to the URL.

See
[Ember Discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/235#issuecomment-22431031) on the matter and for a more complex options see the **how-to** on the [API Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_reset).